# Bad request error and Case field data formats

Tags: rest-api, case, rest

I am quite new to Salesforce development. I am working on Laravel project that sends data collected from the users to Salesforce using Salesforce's REST API. The data collected from the users corresponds to various fields on the case object as well as user specific data using which I can create a user account or access an existing user account. 
I am using a guzzle based custom built Salesforce client to handle the REST API calls. I am able to create the user account and query for that account using data provided by the user. However, when I am trying to create a case using the input data from the user, I am often getting a 400 error. I understand that the error code corresponds to 'Bad Request', which means there is some issue with the data that I am sending to Salesforce.

My question is, how can I debug this issue further? Also, how can I understand the correct format for a field? For example, if  I am sending a date to Salesforce, it should be formatted in ISO5601; if I am sending multi pick list values, it should be serialised and so on.

EDIT:

```
[{"message":"Geocode: id value of incorrect type: 2","errorCode":"MALFORMED_ID","fields":["geopointe__Geocode__c"]}]
```

While debugging, I got this response. I understand that the issue is related to the geocode field in this case. How can I get all the valid values for geocode field so that the user can make selection out of these values?